# Cannot find CLCircularRegion in scope in swift

Tags: swift, core-location

There is an error which states that the analyzer cannot find CLCircularRegion, is it deprecated?

```
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinates, radius: 100, identifier: UUID().uuidString)
```

Comment: Did you import `CoreLocation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the import statement

```
import CoreLocation
```